# How to toggle PouchDB live synchronisation

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I want that i can turn the live synchronisation on and off, but it's not getting on again.

```
function startSync() {
    localdbSync = localDB.sync(remoteDB, {live: true});
}

function stopSync() {
    localdbSync.cancel();
}

$scope.toggleSync = function () {
        if (localDB.sync.canceled == true) {
            startSync();
        } else {
            stopSync();
        }
    };
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind, same code with using a service now works.